# maintaing metadata while ERC721 cross-chain transfer

Tags: erc-721, cross-chain, layer-2

I want to make any ERC721 token (on any contract) to be transferable from ethereum to MATIC chain (fully compatible with EVM with deployed support contracts on ethereum). So I am doing the following two-step process:

- "**Container**" ERC721 contract on ethereum and "**childContainer**" with default `safeTransfer` and `onERC721Received` implemented, metadata for any token minted on this contract will be stored in `http://baseURI/tokenId` format.
- "**Container**" contract will approve [`ERC721Predicate`](https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/ethereum-matic/pos/using-sdk/erc721) and [`rootChainManager`](https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/ethereum-matic/pos/getting-started) contracts deployed by MATIC on ethereum which will lock specific token and mint the same tokenId on MATIC chain contract "**childContainer**" (called by childChainManager deployed by MATIC). Fully managed automatically by calling a single function.

I am facing an issue while transferring metadata of tokens that are not minted on the **Container** contract. A tokenId on any external contract can change `owner` to **Container** by calling the transfer method by the current owner. But how do I transfer metadata cross-chain, I can query metadata but it can be any URL and all tokens minted on **Container** are in `http://baseURI/tokenId` format where baseURI set on MATIC chain `childContainer` manually once as soon as it is deployed so metadata can be the query with just `tokenId` but that is not the case with tokens minted on any other ERC721 contract except **Container**